# How to build the text area dynamically?

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

i have got some doubt in my project, i have a text box in that text box if i change the font family font size and font color its getting changed, but actually my requirement is when i enter anything in that text box and later if i change any thing like size color and all it should get changed, alternatively my text box is in static but what to do if i need it in dynamic how to do that can any one guide me

```
            <?php
            $font = "courier";
            $size = "";
            $color = "";

            if(isset($_GET['font'])){
                $font = $_GET['font'];
            }

            if(isset($_GET['size'])){
                $size = $_GET['size'];
            }

            if(isset($_GET['color'])){
                $color = $_GET['color'];
            }
            ?>

            <div style="padding-left:130px ; padding-top:50px">

                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Something" style="font-family: <?php echo $font; ?> ; font-size: <?php echo $size; ?> ; color: <?php echo $color; ?>">the quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog.</textarea>

                <br><br>
                <div>
                    <a href="?font=arial">Arial</a> 
                    <a href="?font=times">Times</a>
                    <a href="?font=impact">Impact</a> 
                    <a href="?font=verdana">Verdana</a>
                </div>

                <br><br>
                <div>
                    <a href="?size=30px">30px</a> 
                    <a href="?size=10px">10px</a>
                    <a href="?size=50px">50px</a> 
                    <a href="?size=60px">60px</a>
                </div>

                <br><br>
                <div>
                    <a href="?color=red">RED</a> 
                    <a href="?color=pink">PINK</a>
                    <a href="?color=blue">BLUE</a> 
                    <a href="?color=yellow">YELLOW</a>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: You mean when you click on any of these `<a>` you want to get the respective changes.

Comment: yes sir, when i enter anything in the text area and later if i select any a tag it should change.

Comment: But, the why you are going to implement will remove the content of the text area due to page refresh. It means, if you added some text, and then click on any of the tags, the page will be refreshed and after page refresh you will get the new CSS applied to the text area but there won't be the text you had entered before. But the new text you will write will be having the new css you applied.

Comment: I would suggest to use jquery instead. It will give you scope that you can change css without refresh and that will be applied to the text you wrote instantly.

Comment: Apply style by ajax request or use jquery for performing this operation

Comment: sir i know how to do it in jquery but i have been said to do it in php only

Comment: sir any idea how to do it ?

Comment: for php only you can use ajax request for click event on anchor tag

Comment: ok sir i will try n let u know

Comment: sir is their any possibility of doing only in php

Comment: The main problem here is that either of those links will only ever pass _one_ of the _three_ parameters you need. You would either need to put the right “combination” of all three into each one of those links (keep the _current_ value for the other two the link is not supposed to change), or keep previous user choices in a _session_.

Comment: sir can you please edit my code and let me know because im not understanding what u said

Comment: sir can u atleast guide me how to put those link in dropdown menu?

Comment: sir can u atleast tel me how to put those links in dropdown menu?